# Probability of the number of tosses to get heads dependent?

Tags: probability

I understand if a fair coin is tossed repeatedly, the probability of getting a head during each toss does not change and is independent from that of other tosses.

What about the number of tosses required to get heads - are they dependent?

For example let X be the random variable representing number of tosses required to get the first head, and Y the random variable representing the number of tosses to get the first two heads. Are the two variables dependent?

Intuitively it seems that Y depends on X. What is a more 'formal' reasoning than mere intuition?

Comment: Not sure I follow.  As it stands , of course they are dependent.  If it takes you $20$ tosses to get the first head, then it is impossible that you got two heads in the first $5$ tosses.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: The number of tosses has a negative binomial distribution. The questions is whether X (number of tosses getting the 1st head) and Y (number of tosses getting the first two heads) are independent.

Comment: And as I remarked, they are obviously dependent.  Do you think $P(X=3, Y=2)\,=\,P(X=3)\times P(Y=2)$?  Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: I do not think P(X=x, Y= y) = P((X = x) * P(Y = y). What I am asking is a more formal "proof".  I have the distribution function for P(X) and P(Y) respectively, both follow the negative binomial distribution. But I cannot figure out the joint distribution P(X, Y)....

Comment: What I wrote is a formal proof. Just compute both sides and verify that they are not equal.

Comment: That's the problem: I do not know how the joint distribution P(X,Y) should look like. Hence I can't prove P(X,Y) = P(X) P(Y).

Comment: You can't figure out what the probability that $(X,Y)=(3,2)$ is? You hardly need the full joint distribution to do that.

Comment: Don't rely on heavy formulas and such.  You can compute all the necessary probabilities from first principles.

Answer (score 0):

We have $Pr(X=3) >0$ and $Pr(Y=2)>0$

But $$Pr(X=3, Y=2) =0  \ne Pr(X=3)Pr(Y=2)$$

Hence, they are dependent.

Note that we do not need the whole distribution explicitly.

We know the joint distribution requireds $X < Y$ to be positive. But $X$ follows a geometric distribution while $Y$ follows the sum of two geometric distributions.